# Missing gdbserver binary in OpenWRT/LEDE

Tags: gdb, openwrt, gdbserver

I cloned LEDE repository from github and wanted to debug my simple program on router. To do this, I configured LEDE build (like here: https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/devel/gdb) using menuconfig:

```
Advanced configuration options (for developers) → Toolchain Options → Build gdb
Development → gdbserver
Development → gdb
```

Then I compiled my simple program with -ggdb3 flag and wanted to start debugging. However, it is impossible because gdbserver binary seems to be missing on router after sysupgrade (it does not appear in /bin, /sbin, /usr/bin, /usr/sbin). Have I missed something in this configuration?

Comment: "Then I compiled my simple program" you also need to rebuild the system image. It wasn't clear to me from documentation whether `sysupgrade` does that or not.

Comment: Yes, for me it was also not clear, but that was not the problem in this case. Look at my answer, maybe it will save your time some day...

Answer (score 1):

OK, I figured it out. When you build the system image and total package size is bigger than your available ROM (in my case 4MB), your .bin in /bin/targets/ directory won't be updated and you will get your old image. Everything without any warning message!